# Деятельность "в 2017 году" или "за 2017 год"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

О докладе Уполномоченного по правам человека в субъекте РФ "О деятельности Уполномоченного по правам человека в 2017 году (за 2017 год)"?

Answer (score 1):

**О докладе Уполномоченного по правам человека в субъекте РФ "О деятельности Уполномоченного по правам человека в 2017 году"**

или

**О докладе Уполномоченного по правам человека в субъекте РФ "О деятельности Уполномоченного по правам человека" за 2017 год**

или

**О докладе Уполномоченного по правам человека в субъекте РФ "Об итогах  деятельности Уполномоченного по правам человека за 2017 год"**

Деятельность **в** 2017 году, а доклад **за** 2017 год, итоги **за** 2017 год.

Comment: *Деятельность в 2017 году,* - без контекста - не факт.

Answer (score 1):

Если придерживаться общего стиля таких документов, то "в ... году" (примеры - у М_Г).

Если же говорить вообще - о грамматической составляющей, то вариант "за не будет неправильным", хотя и режет слух своей непривычностью и кажущейся стилистической небрежностью.

Просто тут смысл разный. Помимо манипуляций с кавычками (см. там же), тут есть еще один резон. Деятельность-то, она происходит "в ... году". Но "деятельность за прошедший год" никого решительно не удивит. Предлог "за" тут сам по себе означает поведение итогов, обобщение. Значение относительно новое, совсем недавно воспринималось как канцелярщина. Но оно вполне  возможно.

Итак.
Для официального названия только: 
 ***"О деятельности Уполномоченного по правам человека в 2017 году"***.

Во всех остальных случаях - по контексту.

Если надо указать на какой-то единичный факт, то
*Деятельность конторы "Рога и Копыта" в тысяча девятьсот давнозабытом году была отмечена медалью "За спасение утопающих"*

Если же идет речь об итогах, обобщениях то вполне возможно
*Деятельность фирмы "Вязаные веники" за 1999 год может быть охарактеризована как провальная.*

Answer (score 1):

**Официальный документ:**

Доклад о деятельности Уполномоченного по правам человека в Российской Федерации **за 2016 год** от 17 мая 2017 г.

ГАРАНТ.РУ: http://www.garant.ru/products/ipo/prime/doc/71576208/#ixzz5CwdSfcca

Я думаю, что предлог ЗА учитывает **всю деятельность** за указанный период (в данном случае 2016 год), в то время как предлог В может обозначать **деятельность, отнесенную к этому году** (не обязательно в полном объеме).

**Примеры их Нацкорпуса:**

Вся его **деятельность за двадцатипятилетнее управление им Бухарой** свидетельствовала о его полной преданности России,

Впоследствии, объясняя свою **деятельность за это время**, граф Растопчин в своих записках несколько раз писал...

Вся ваша **деятельность за два года** ограничилась тем ...

На свободу вышли люди, арестованные за активную оппозиционную **деятельность в 2004-2012 годах.** [Мир в 2013 году // «Эксперт», 2014]